# Dynamic currency conversion with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one input field where numeric value will be entered and on another read only field the converted (calculated) value will be displayed dynamically.

I tried with jQuery but it is not working.

Html

```
<form name="curconvert" method="get" action="script/conversion.php">
  <div class="field-row conversion">
       <div class="field1"><input type="text" name="strbasecurrency" id="strbasecurrency" tabindex="1"  value="Start typing..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Start typing...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Start typing...';}" /></div>
        <div class="field2">=</div>
        <div class="field3"><input type="text" name="strconvcurrency" id="strconvcurrency" value="Result" readonly class="converted"></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#strbasecurrency").keydown(function (e) {
    $('.field-row input').css({'color':'#162d3a'});
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $converted == ($("#strbasecurrency").val() * 0.73);
    $("#strconvcurrency").val("$converted");
   });
 });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csw27/)

Comment: FYI you can use the `placeholder` attribute instead of the unsightly code in the `onfocus` and `onblur` methods.

Comment: I want to take care of IE 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had several issues:

1. you use the $converted variable without preceding it with var.
2. You tried to use the `==` operator to assign a value when you should have used `=`
3. When you tried to set the value to the input field, you were enclosing the value in `""`

The updated code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#strbasecurrency").keydown(function (e) {
    $('.field-row input').css({'color':'#162d3a'});
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
            //added "var" and used = instead of ==
    var $converted = ($("#strbasecurrency").val() * 0.73); 
    $("#strconvcurrency").val($converted); //removed double quotes around $converted

});
```

});

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csw27/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the last two lines of your code where the syntax is a little off. Try this:

```
var converted = $("#strbasecurrency").val() * 0.73;
$("#strconvcurrency").val(converted);
```

Also you need to use the `keypress` or `keyup` event on your `strbasecurrency` field.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/csw27/3/)